# Unable to grab values from text boxes on form

Tags: c#, winforms

So i am trying to grab user input from my text boxes which are being printed to the screen through a loop and if Statements. When trying to print the values put into the textbox I only get one value. Here is the code for adding the textboxes to the grid:

```
 private void InsertEasyNums()
    {
            int x = 70;
            int y = 40;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                x = 70;
                y = 160;
            }
            else if(i == 6)
            {
                x = 65;
                y = 280;
            }
            if (easyNums[i] == '0')
            {
                DrawingField.SendToBack();
                int panelX = x + 300;
                int panelY = y + + 100;

                Font newFont = new Font("Arial", 25);
                Point tbLocation = new Point(panelX, panelY);
                userInput[i] = new TextBox();

                userInput[i].Name = "Row[i]TB";
                userInput[i].Font = newFont;
                userInput[i].Width = 50;
                userInput[i].Location = tbLocation;
                userInput[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                userInput[i].BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
                Controls.Add(userInput[i]);
                DrawingField.SendToBack();

                x = x + 145;
                DrawingField.SendToBack();
            }
            else if (easyNums[i] != '0')
            {
                DrawingField.SendToBack();
                Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold);
                Brush Numbers = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                Graphics g = DrawingField.CreateGraphics();
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(easyNums[i]), drawFont, 
                Numbers, x, y);
                x = x + 146;
            }

        }

    }
```

Here is where I try to print the Textboxes:

```
 foreach (Control c in DrawingField.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                int i = 0;
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)c;
                string str = txt.Text;
                TBValues[i] = str;
                i++;


            }
        }
        foreach (var key in TBValues)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(key);
        }
```

ANSWER: I moved the declaration of userInput to the beginning of the method and looped through 9 time to give 9 textboxes then used the if statements to move them and change properties.

Comment: Explain what is your program supposed to do when one uses it.

Comment: Think of Sudoku. Basically there are numbers the user cant change while there are empty boxes for the user to type in a number. I am just having trouble grabbing the values from the text boxes the users are suppose to use.

Comment: Right, here's a pretty good example on how to write a Sudoku in WinForms: https://github.com/gtarawneh/sudoku

Comment: Now what are you trying to achieve, as evidently you're not using numbers? You're looking for the same grid layout and struggling with what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try to move i before the loop

```
       int i = 0;
 foreach (Control c in DrawingField.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {

            TextBox txt = (TextBox)c;
            string str = txt.Text;
            TBValues[i] = str;
            i++;


        }
    }
    foreach (var key in TBValues)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work. when I just try printing with a normal foreach loop I get that userInput[i] = null; I assume this means that when the loop to declare userInput only goes through and doesn't normally increment like 1,2,3 its more like 1, 3, 7 which causes null values on the foreach. When I try to manually populate the array with empty strings I still get the same error...